# EntityType 'MvcHtmlString' has no key defined - MVC 4

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4

I have a page class that includes a variable of type MvcHtmlString.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using System.Globalization;
using SpringHealthOne.SpringWS;
using System.Configuration;

namespace SpringHealthOne.Models
{
    public class Page 
    {
        public int PageID { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public string Title { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public MvcHtmlString PageBody { get; set; }
        public string MetaTitle { get; set; }
        public string MetaDescription { get; set; }
        public string Keywords { get; set; }
        public bool Published { get; set; }
    }
}
```

this in itself is fine, and visual studios 2012 reports no errors or warnings. However, when i attempt to start up the project in debug mode it throws:

> One or more validation errors were detected during model generation:
>
> \tSystem.Data.Entity.Edm.EdmEntityType: : EntityType 'MvcHtmlString'
>   has no key defined. Define the key for this EntityType.
>   \tSystem.Data.Entity.Edm.EdmEntitySet: EntityType: EntitySet
>   'MvcHtmlStrings' is based on type 'MvcHtmlString' that has no keys
>   defined.

the line that thows it is in my MenuController:

```
IEnumerable<MenuItem> menuItems = db.MenuItems.Where(c => c.ParentID == null).OrderBy(c => c.DisplayOrder).Select(c => c);
```

I've followed it through to the database context which calls the Page class, but i cant work out why im seeing the error specifically.

Context:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Data.Entity;
using System.Data.Entity.ModelConfiguration;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;
using SpringHealthOne.App_Start;
using System.Web.Mvc;

namespace SpringHealthOne.Models
{
    public class SpringerContext : DbContext
    {
        public DbSet<MenuItem> MenuItems { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Page> Pages { get; set; }

        protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            Database.SetInitializer<SpringerContext>(new SpringerContextInitializer());

            modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(new MenuItemConfiguration());
            base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);


        }
    }
}
```

Im very new to C#, even more so to MVC. Any help would be awesome.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`MvcHtmlString` is not primitive type, so you cannot save it directly to field of database. And entity type requires ID property (otherwise you will not be able to set foreign key in database). Use simple `string` instead of `MvcHtmlString` if you want to store your `Page` objects in database.

Also you can mark this property as not mapped and create string property which will be saved to database:

```
[NotMapped]
public MvcHtmlString PageBody { get; set; }

public string Body
{
    get { return PageBody.ToHtmlString(); }
    set { PageBody = new MvcHtmlString(value); }
}
```

Comment: Ah, that would explain a lot!. In that case, how do i save HTML to the database? which is why i was trying to use MvcHtmlString in the first place :)

Comment: @N1ghteyes I have updated answer with sample which shows how you can have property of MvcHtmlString type in your code, and property of string type for saving data to database

Comment: Thanks, I now have a validation issue, but i'll post that in a new question if need to :)